# How to get Context in Android from flutter without creating PluginRegistry.Registrar

Tags: android, flutter, dart, call-recording

---

I don't want to create a plugin but want to get Context in Android. Is there any way to do so.

I am trying to achieve a call recording functionality and want to use *getExternalFilesDir* method.

I refered this [link](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/battery/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/battery/BatteryPlugin.java). But here they get Context using PluginRegistry.Registrar.

```
public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
    final BatteryPlugin instance = new BatteryPlugin();
    instance.onAttachedToEngine(registrar.context(), registrar.messenger());
  }
```

Guide me through it.